# How to refer different table by ID?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a main table that needs to hold references to other tables.
Table users has an ID, and another table's REF_ID.

```
Table users
===========
ID   TABLE_ID   REF_ID  NAME
============================
1    1          1       John
2    2          20      Stacey
.    .          .       .
.    .          .       .
n    2          324     Ben

Table Posts(1)
===========
ID   TITLE
===========
1    "hey there!"
2    "what's up?"
.    .
.    .
n    "Look what I found!"

Table Comments(2)
===========
ID   CONTENT
===========
1    "yes, looks amazing"
2    "Wow!"
.    .
.    .
n    "yep"
```

The main table holds a long list of users. Each of which has either a post or a comment.
My questio is how do I work with them?

1. To insert: I guess I Should commit 2 different queries to insert, first is the insert to the related post/comment table, getting the `lastInsertId` and then feeding that ID to the main refs table, correct?
2. How can I in one query, **using only the main table (users) ID's**, get the relevant info as well as from which table I got it, such as:

   ```
   ID   REF_ID   NAME   TITLE
   1    1        John   "hey there!"
   ```

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: edited. missing info

Comment: second point mean  SELECT users.ID, users.REF_ID , users.NAME,  IF(users.TABLE_ID = 1, Posts.TITLE, Comments.TITLE) AS TITLE FROM ((users LEFT JOIN  Posts ON users.TABLE_ID = 1 AND 
Posts.ID = users.REF_ID) LEFT JOIN Comments ON users.TABLE_ID = 2 AND
Comments.ID = users.REF_ID)

Comment: `get the relevant info as well ` explain the logic for the relevant info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have a bad design, to solve it right now you have to do this:

```
 SELECT u.ID,   u.REF_ID,   u.NAME,   p.TITLE
 FROM users u
 JOIN posts p
   ON u.ref_id = p.ID
 WHERE u.TABLE_ID = 1 

 UNION ALL

 SELECT u.ID,   u.REF_ID,   u.NAME,   c.CONTENT
 FROM users u
 JOIN comments c
   ON u.ref_id = c.ID
 WHERE u.TABLE_ID = 2
```

A better design should be join Posts and Comments on the same table

Table users

```
ID   REF_ID  NAME
```

Table posts

```
REF_ID  TYPE_ID TITLE
```

This way your `REF_ID` is unique. In your version you can have Ref_id =1 and that can be either on table Post or table comments.

Type_id can be 1 or 2 depending if is a post or a comment. Also allow you add other types later if you need. At different of previous model where you will need add a new table.

Finally the query become easier:

```
 SELECT u.ID,   u.REF_ID,   u.NAME,   p.TITLE
 FROM users u
 JOIN posts p
   ON u.ref_id = p.ID
 -- WHERE u.TYPE_ID = 1   // optional
```

Comment: what could be a better design?

Comment: It's not a bad design. It's just a different design, but perfectly common.

Comment: @Strawberry Ok maybe common, but for this case isnt my suggestion better?

Comment: You're suggestion is fine. I can't say that it's better.

Answer (score 0):

1- I didn't understood the question, sorry.

2- It's the principle of joins :

```
SELECT u.ID, u.REF_ID, u.Name, p.Title
FROM users u
INNER JOIN posts p ON p.ID = u.REF_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Visit https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/primary-and-foreign-key-constraints

You have to make "ID" as a Primary and "REF_ID" as Foreign key.
The Foreign key of the main table will be the Primary key of your other two tables.
Simple, You have to make relationships between these tables.

Visit https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/pdf/sql-foreign-key.pdf
for more on tables relationship.

Comment: He doesn't have to... It will be better if he wants his query to work fast